# Constructor SQLiteDatabase cannot be applied in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

> error: constructor SQLiteDatabase in class SQLiteDatabase cannot be
>   applied to given types; required: no arguments found: MainActivity
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

It shows error on line:

`sqLiteDatabase=new SQLiteDatabase(this);`

**Error**

this is a code in my main activity

```
package com.notify.fahadkhan.myapplication;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{


    EditText edt1,edt2;
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4;
    private database database;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// this line has been generated an error
        sqLiteDatabase=new SQLiteDatabase(this);

        btn1=findViewById(R.id.btnin);
        btn2=findViewById(R.id.btndel);
        btn3=findViewById(R.id.btnup);
        btn4=findViewById(R.id.btnview);
        edt1=findViewById(R.id.edt1);
        edt2=findViewById(R.id.edt2);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnin:
                String firstname=edt1.getText().toString();
                String lastname=edt2.getText().toString();
                sqLiteDatabase.insertStdudent(firstname,lastname);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added comment where I am getting error.

```
> SQLiteDatabase is not public and it cannot be accessed outside the
> package.
```

I have checked everywhere in my code, it is public. I am new with databases in  android. Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `public` constructor for `SQLiteDatabase`. You do not create instances using a constructor. You obtain instances by either calling a `static` method on `SQLiteDatabase` (e.g., `openOrCreateDatabase()`) or by using other classes that will do that for you (e.g., `SQLiteOpenHelper`).

This is covered briefly in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite). It is also covered in many books and courses on Android app development.